# users are logged out of my asp.net site once a day. how do I fix it in iis7?

Tags: iis-7, authentication

My application uses Forms authentication to log users into the site with their Active Directory credentials. We just switched servers for the app and now they are logged out about once a day. It doesn't appear to be a browser issue (affects all browsers, even after clearing cache and cookies). How do I fix this in IIS7?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably AppPool recycling. Turn it off. [This post](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling) shows you where you can change it.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't turn it off, I would set it to do once a day off-hours, if you have off-hours.